# IDE Screen madness in both Android Studio and vscode with flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get started learning flutter on windows 10 using either vscode or android studio.  I am using dual monitors which has caused me some problem.  However even with one disabled I'm still seeing the problem.

When the sdk is invoked one of my monitors blanks.  If it's from an ide project, one of the monitors goes into an infinite blanking/restoring mode which I cannot explain.

I have two videos showing what's happening.  [Doctor/VSCode demo](https://youtu.be/aKWNAAk0JTs) and [Android Studio Demo](https://youtu.be/SNT9d-rp1Ok).  The second video ends early but it basically was showing that the same thing happens when I reset the UI scaling to 100% on the main monitor.  I am not so good at video editing but these show what I'm trying to troubleshoot.

I am aware this may not be a flutter sdk issue per se, but I don't encounter it with other project types.

Any insight appreciated.  I'd like to learn flutter but this has me stumped.

what I tried tl/dnr: I tried creating flutter projects using vscode and android studio and it sent my primary monitor into an unrelenting reset mode until I closed the IDE.